# Can't turn computer on after re-attaching hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, power, eee-pc

I have an Eee PC 1008HA. A few days before I got a virus that was preventing the Windows to boot but I could turn the computer on.

I opened (disassembled) the Eee PC, then disconnected the hard disk. I connected the hard disk to another computer and copied my files.

When I connected again the hard disk to my Eee PC and closed (assembled) it , I cannot turn the Eee PC on. Even when I connect the wire for charging, neither the charging light nor any other lights light up.

Comment: Does it boot with no hard drive? Could you have accidentally disconnected another cable in the process?

Comment: No it doesn't even turned on. I see all the connectios are ok.

Comment: Have you tried if it charges (or detects a charged battery) when you just connect the bare mainboard with the battery and power supply? If it is not you likely broke the mainboard (excessive bending, ESD, short due to screw lost inside).

Comment: The charging light is off when I connect the power supply. It doesn't show if it is charging or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it has anything to do with the harddrive. It appears that during disassembly or reassembly you broke the power supply circuits or disconnected a wire. Alternatively you damaged the motherboard due to electrostatic discharge.